# How much money/time should be re-invested in your own business, as a contractor?

Tags: small-business, business

As a contractor, you realize how valuable your time is - but undoubtedly, an investment back into skills update training or in marketing your business is worth the time you would otherwise spend billing clients for your services.

What is a recommended proportion of time to spend on these types of activities?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I am self employed.. and I spend what ever time is necessary to learn the required skills... this year I spent hundreds of hours learning about website development.  Ultimately it's your choice... if you can outsource some of the learning curve, why not...  You either need to have the skills yourself, or know people who can do the work for you. BTW.. finding the right people is another skill.